# How to turn up a linux bridge while booting ubuntu machine?

Tags: network-bridge

I want a linux bridge to get installed and turned up while booting an Ubuntu(14.04) machine. The bridge should be attached to eth0 interface. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to bridging network interfaces myself, so i am not sure if this is the perfect solution: On your machine there is a file /etc/network/interfaces, in which your interfaces (and bridges) are defined. To this file, you can add the following:

```
 auto br0
 iface br0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.2
       network 192.168.1.0
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       broadcast 192.168.1.255
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       bridge_ports eth0
```

Be aware that this will assign a static ip to the bridge interface, and you may have to change all the IP adresses considering your network structure (e.g. change the gateway address to your gateway/router). The important aspects considering your question are the `auto br0`, which will automatically bring the bridge up on boot, and the `bridge_ports eth0`which attaches the bridge to eth0 as you wished. For further information on bridging interfaces, you might have a look [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html).

Comment: Yes, I want a static ip for the bridge. I even tried auto br0 but it did not bring the bridge up and I had to do it manually by ifup br0. Is there any other way?

Comment: Just to make sure, you did reboot after using the auto option? Afaik this should bring the interface up automatically. This worked for me...

Comment: Can you post the content of your /etc/network/interfaces? Then i could look into it further. I'm especially interested in the entry for eth0, i think that could prevent the bridge from starting automatically. It looks like this in my case:
`auto eth0`
`iface eth0 inet manual`

Comment: Here's the content:-      

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 10.110.80.120
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 10.110.83.253
bridge_ports eth0

Comment: Hm, looks good to me, sry i don't know what is wrong then...